# How do I map data from state to component prop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb

To start with I'm a beginner. Any help would be appreciated.
So I'm getting my data from mongoDB atlas using node+express API. I'm successfull at getting the array to show up in console log using following code.

```
const [product, setProduct] = useState();
    const url = "http://localhost:5000/api/items";

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(url).then((res) => {
            setProduct(res.data);
            // setProduct(
            //     JSON.stringify({
            //         title: setProduct.title,
            //         price: setProduct.price, 
            //         image: setProduct.image,
            //         details: setProduct.details,
            //     })
            // );
        })
    }, [url])
    console.log(product)
```

The console log displays the array properly as collection named 'items' with content of arrays. As you can see I tried to stringify the response as the response returns JSON but again I didn't know how to map Following is the code where I tried to map the contents like id, name etc as props to component.

```
              <div>
                  {product.map((product) => {
                          <Product name={product.title} />
                  })}
              </div>
```

When I do this I get error that the map is not a function. I don't know what I'm doing wrong here. I know I'm supposed to use redux or reducer/context here but I want to get this to work before updating it with those.

[![Response from res.data][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/auxvl.png

Comment: Please include the full details. Specifically the exact error message, and the value of `res.data`.

Comment: @Brian Thompson
 I've attached an image of the console.log(product).

Comment: `product.items.map`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you didnt get yours products.

As we can see from screenshot

`res.data` equal to object with one property `items`:
`res.data`= `{items: []}`
and we need to take/access to these items

use this: `setProducts(res?.data?.items || [])`

```
const [products, setProducts] = useState();
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(url).then((res) => {
            setProducts(res?.data?.items || []);
        })
    }, [url])
```

```
              <div>
                  {products?.map((product) => {
                          <Product name={product.title} />
                  })}
              </div>
```

Comment: Appreciate the response, now all the errors like product?.map is not a function are gone. But the component is not being displayed yet. Maybe I'm using props wrong like this title={products.title}. Should I do it like {products.items.title} ?

Comment: need to return `<Product name={product.title} />` from map, `{products?.map((product) => <Product name={product.title} />)}` OR `{products?.map((product) => { return <Product name={product.title} />})}`

Comment: `products.items.title` - no, no. So, you are getting ProductS (plural), you are mapping products, one iteration has one product, to acces product property just use dot (better with optional chaining operator OR just `?`) - `product?.title`

Comment: Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it. It works finally. Was stuck on this for days looking up for solutions for similar problem. Thanks  shutsman from the bottom of my heart. P.S- Sorry for being such a noob. I don't have enough reputation to upvote your answer but be sure I'll do it when i get enough rep. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

On the first render the value for types will be undefined ( on sync code execution ), try using it as

```
<div>
   {product?.map((product) => {
   <Product name={product.name} />
   })}
   </div>
```

? will make sure to run map once value for types is there ( also make sure it is mappable ( is an array ))

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I got errors same as before product.map is not a function and can't perform state update on unmounted component.